# Pandas Fill NaN with Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,np.nan],
                   'B':[2.2,np.nan,2.2]})           
df

    A       B
0   1.0     2.2
1   1.0     NaN
2   NaN     2.2
```

If I want to replace the NaN value in column A with the value that repeats in that column (1) and do the same for column B, what sort of fillna() do I need to use?

```
    A       B
0   1.0     2.2
1   1.0     NaN
2   NaN     2.2
```

Looking for a generic solution as I really have thousands of rows.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')

# df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, np.nan, 2], 'B': [2.2, np.nan, 2.2, 1.9]})
# df.fillna(method='ffill')
#   A    B
#0  1  2.2
#1  1  2.2
#2  1  2.2
#3  2  1.9
```

Comment: It's not clear from the OP if the fill value should just be the previous, or the most common value in the column.

Comment: hum i understood it as the previous value but you may be right.

Comment: From my example, this is the sort of simple answer I was looking for. However, what if I wanted to fill with the most common value? I'm ultimately trying to fill blanks resulting from a df.loc and groupby-transform procedure which leaves some row values blank

Comment: I'm going to post another related question in a minute that better summarizes what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Transpose first, then `ffil` or `bfill`:
`df.T.ffill().bfill().T`

Answer (score 3):

`fillna` can take dictionary of values where the key is the column name.

Assuming you want to fill the columns with the value that is repeated the most, you can compute the dictionary with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, np.nan, 2], 
    'B': [2.2, np.nan, 2.2, 1.9]
})
fill_dict = df.mode().to_dict(orient='records')[0]
df = df.fillna(values=fill_dict)
df

   A    B
0  1  2.2
1  1  2.2
2  1  2.2
3  2  1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import operator

def most_common(L):
  # get an iterable of (item, iterable) pairs
  SL = sorted((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(L))
  # print 'SL:', SL
  groups = itertools.groupby(SL, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
  # auxiliary function to get "quality" for an item
  def _auxfun(g):
    item, iterable = g
    count = 0
    min_index = len(L)
    for _, where in iterable:
      count += 1
      min_index = min(min_index, where)
    # print 'item %r, count %r, minind %r' % (item, count, min_index)
    return count, -min_index
  # pick the highest-count/earliest item
  return max(groups, key=_auxfun)[0]
```

and then just add

```
df['A'].fillna(most_common(df['A'].values.tolist()))
```

Comment: I'm impressed with your implementation of `mode` with itertools. But even if we forget for a moment that pandas dataframes have their own `mode` method, using numpy's mode function would surely be much more reliable.

Comment: Ya I agree ... i just forgot about mode so I done this ... Dont know if its correct ans or not !!!!